# Sum of Previous Time Filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with dates and amounts.

On my page, I would like a gage visualization where I am displaying the sum of payments from this month (page filter) and I would like the sum of payments from the previous month.

I think I need to make a measure to do this (that may be excluded from the page filter).

Tried:

I've added a date (calendar) table and my statement looks like this

and tried this as well,

```
PrevMonth =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'analyticdev PaymentsLabeled'[amount] ),
    PREVIOUSMONTH ( 'Date'[Date] )
)
```

and tried

```
PrevMonth =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'analyticdev PaymentsLabeled'[amount] ),
    DATEADD ( 'Date'[Date], -1, MONTH )
)
```

I am getting a blank when I put the measure on the page.

analyticdev PaymentsLabeled table:

```
paymentdate amount
7/20/2018 10:31:50 PM $100.00
...
4/30/2019 7:32:32 PM $1,516.66
```

Date table:

```
Date
7/1/2015 12:00:00 AM
...
1/31/2025 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Please show us your table(s) with relevant columns and some data

Comment: your page filter - do you use the one from date table or the one from fact table? I have a vague feeling, that you should use the one from the date table, which might solve the issue.

Comment: @Aldert, added the tables.

Comment: @PavelKlammert, my code has the one from the date table, but I've tried both.

Comment: I assume, that you have a filter or slicer present on the page. From which table does it come from? 
Because if it comes from Date table, your calculations should work, i believe.